# How to get all <li> elements under <ul> in selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When this `<ul>` element is clicked, only 8-10 `<li>` show up. There are 50 `<li>` elements but need to scroll all the way down to see all of them, if I write below code -

```
company = self.driver.find_element_by_id('ul-0')
company_list = company.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
```

company_list gives only 8-10 values , but I want all the 50 values.

Comment: *"need to scroll all the way down to see all of them"* Could you elaborate please? At a guess, I would say that these elements are being loaded via AJAX, which is only triggered when you scroll to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @Narendra Rajput, every time I scroll, at a time 10 elements are shown.

Comment: I have deduced that I will have to scroll down to get all the li's, not possible without scrolling as said by @Narendra Rajput it is being loaded by ajax